# Having difficulty posting from a sample REST API to my local host

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

Everytime I click the add-friend button, my REST data doesn't post on my localhost. I'm thinking I put the settings in wrong. But not sure where I went wrong.

Here's the link to the RESTful API:
http://rest.learncode.academy/

Here's the HTML code:

```
<h1>jQuery Ajax</h1>
        <h2>Friends</h2>

        <ul id="friends">

        </ul>

        <h4>Add a Friend</h4>
        <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
        <p> age: <input type="text" id="age"></p>
        <button id="add-friend">Add!</button>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
$(function(){
var $friends = $('#friends');
var $name = $('#name');
var $age = $('#age');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function(friends){
        $.each(friends, function(i, friend){
            $friends.append('<li>name: '+friend.name+' , age: '+friend.age+' </li>');


        })

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error loading errors');
    }
});

$('#add-friend').on('click', function(){
    var friend = {
        name: $name.val(),
        age: $age.val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends' ,
        data: {name: 'Billy Bob', age: 27},
        success: function(data){
            $friend.append('<li>name: '+ data.name +', age: '+ data.age + '</li>');

        }
    });


});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post to another server via AJAX. This means that only requests to the same domain your code runs on are allowed.

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific? I'm doing this tutorial and

Comment: When you have a domain where your code runs on, e.g. "www.example.com", there are no Ajax requests allowed to other domains. This is for security reasons. Imagine, I would put bad js-code on that domain and send an ajax request to e.g. amazon.com.
If this would be possible and you are logged in on amazon I could do evil things. Same here: from localhost, no requests to learncode.academy are allowed.

More on that issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: So pretty much swtich the url to my localhost>?

Comment: How would I set up my code to allow myself to set up an ajax request to learncode.academy...i really want to know

Comment: The requests have to go to the localhost... Do you have a server installed on your local machine? Perhaps you can re-route the requests from localhost to lerncode?

Comment: Yes, i'm utilizing mamp. But how do you set up the url to point to the localhost

Comment: You can solve it with a .htaccess in you apache.
1. Create a new subfolder called learncode_api on your www directory.
2. put a file called .htaccess in there
3. put the following contents in the .htaccess file:
http://pastebin.com/PeqwxbVY
Change the URLs in your code to http://localhost/learncode_api/api/johnbob/friends
it will redirect to the old URL in your code. All other URLs not containing /learncode_api will remain untouched.